# a command line java client to consume SOAP - WSLD

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have to write a command line java program to consume a SOAP (wsdl) web service. I do not have a luxury to installed any java libraries I want. So I am going to have to write most of it myself. What can use? or where can I start? Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can't install some additional libs, you have to take a look at [wsimport](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/wsimport.html) tool, to generate web-service client stubs. This tool is provided with JDK, so, I suppose, it could be available for you.

You can find a number of examples, how to ise it on internet, [here is one of them](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/), take a look at the chapter 2, called "Java Web Service Client via wsimport tool"

Answer (score 0):

The executable code for the client should be generated from WSDL file of the web service:

```
wsimport http://localhost:8080/someservice/YourService?WSDL
```

Then you'll get the client classes to access to the web service. Then you need to write a simple client.

```
public class YourServiceClient {
   @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation="http://localhost:8080/someservice/YourService?WSDL")
   private static YourService yourService;

   public void doSomething() {
      // get service port and perform some logic      
   }

   public static void main() {
      new YourServiceClient().doSomething();
   }
}
```

To provide the resources for work with the standalone client (not deployed on the application server) you can use:

```
appclient -client yourserviceclient.jar
```

See Also:

[GlassFish Server Tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadf.html)

Comment: Do you really think, one should use appclient and run some lightweight container just to use stubs generated by wsimport? And plain java-se application is not enough for that?